# Issue in Tableview lazy loading

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, lazy-loading

I have tableview name "tableAll", array "thumbVideoListArray" (first this array is empty) and have array "objDelegate.listVidArray"  which have url of image..  think i have mistakes checks.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if([thumbVideoListArray count] == 0)
        {
            [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(fetchImage:) toTarget:self withObject:indexPath];
        }
        else
        {
             UIImage *img1 = [thumbVideoListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            if(img1)
            {

                cell.thumbImage =  [thumbVideoListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            }
            else
            {
                [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(fetchImage:) toTarget:self withObject:indexPath];
            }
        }
}

- (void)fetchImage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSLog(@"in thead");

if([[[[objDelegate.listVidArray objectAtIndex:[objDelegate.listVidArray count]-(indexPath.section+1)]valueForKey:@"videoList"]valueForKey:@"media_id"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row])
{
    NSData *dataImage = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[[objDelegate.listVidArray objectAtIndex:[objDelegate.listVidArray count]-(indexPath.section+1)]valueForKey:@"videoList"]valueForKey:@"img"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];


    if([dataImage length])
    {

        UIImage *imageThumb = [UIImage imageWithData:dataImage];

        [thumbVideoListArray addObject:imageThumb];

        // Reload rows with the fetched image in other thread
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTable:) withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section]] waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}

}

- (void)reloadTable:(NSArray *)array
{

[tableAll reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

 }
```

Comment: the fetchImage method call every time

Comment: [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) is best code for lazyloading .... Easy and Smooth :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) for lazy loading images from web

Answer (score 0):

In -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: you never grab your cell object. You need to dequeue a reusable cell before setting its properties. You also need to return the cell.

Comment: no i used that but because i don't want to increase the size of the code

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is then? Your question doesn't actually contain a question...

Answer (score 0):

You need some modification as this is not a good way, instead of it, what you can do, you just call your fetch procedure either at viewDidLoad or at viewWillAppear according to your requirement and after that just reload your table...and more importantly not to forget to make use of NSOperation here and tag your loaded data so it can adjust with your cells...Hope, it'll sort your problem...as I've done so many times.